# Is there a way in Perl to sort excel worksheets?

Tags: excel, sorting, perl

The excel workbook was created in perl using Excel::Writer::xlsx.  The first worksheet is a summary worksheet, the second sheet is the detail worksheet, then there can be any number of additional (smaller) worksheets that will be linked to from the summary worksheet.

The summary worksheet should remain as sheet 1, the detail worksheet as sheet 2, but the additional worksheets I'd like to reorganize so they are alphabetical by the tab name.  I have not found a way to do this sort in a perl script.

The other thing that I was hoping to do was to hide the additional worksheets until the user clicks the hyperlink on the summary worksheet.  I was able to hide the worksheets, but when the link was clicked it could not open the hidden worksheet.   When the sheets are not hidden, they hyperlinks work properly. Is there away to make the hyperlink open a hidden worksheet?

Below is an example of how I would like the sheets to be arranged.  My actual file has over 50 additional worksheets.

worksheet - Worksheet Name
Sheet1 - Summary
Sheet2 - Detail
Sheet3 - trains
Sheet4 - cars
sheet5 - planes

I want ordered as:
Sheet1 - Summary
Sheet2 - Detail
Sheet4 - cars
Sheet5 - planes
Sheet3 - trains

Ideally, I would like Sheet 3,4 and 5 to be hidden. Summary sheet will have three hyperlinks.  When a user clicks on the hyperlink it would unhide and display the linked worksheet.

Comment: And post an example excel file or a link to one